Adding a method to an existing enum in Python
I have an existing enumeration with a number of values defined in package b, and I want to add behavior in the current package a.  I understand that you can't directly subclass an enum with existing members but I am trying to reuse the existing names/values without having to duplicate them.
I found two workarounds that function but the IDE is not aware of the method or the enumerations.

Simply monkey-patch the enum and add the method, e.g.:

def foo(cls, identifier: str):
    return a.A(namespace=cls.value, identifier=identifier)


from b.enumerations import B

B.__call__ = foo

This works but the IDE indicates that B is not callable.

Create a new enum from the members of the old enum with a callable type via the functional API, e.g.

class AEnumItem(str):
    def __call__(self, identifier: str) -> a.A:
        return a.A(
            namespace=str(self), identifier=identifier)


class AEnumBase(AEnumItem, enum.Enum):
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.value


import b

B = AEnumBase('B', [(item.name, AEnumItem(item.value)) for item in b.B])


But this also does not allow IDE to autocomplete the members of AEnum like it does with B.
Is there anything simpler that I am missing that allows for the IDE to recognize the members of the new enum?

Since this is an IDE issue, which IDE are you using?

JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA w/ the Python plugin
